# Unable to load the CINNA package

Tags: r

I tried loading the 'CINNA' package into R. Used the following commands.

```
install.packages("CINNA")
library(CINNA)
```

It runs for a while and then this error message pops up:

> Error in library(CINNA) : there is no package called ‘CINNA’

Please help me work around this.
Thanks.

Comment: Is it there in `installed.packages()`?

Comment: Seems it did not install properly. Look for error messages after the install step.

Comment: @neilfws I do get the following warnings  

1. downloaded length 3297280 != reported length 4324736  

2. Warning in install.packages :
  error 1 in extracting from zip file
Warning in install.packages :
  cannot open compressed file 'XML/DESCRIPTION', probable reason 'No such file or directory'
Error in install.packages : cannot open the connection

Comment: Sounds like the package file download was incomplete. I just installed from CRAN with no issues. Maybe a temporary network issue.

Comment: @neilfws, that is exactly what I thought the first time I encountered this issue. But I somehow always run into this problem every time I try installing the CINNA package. Tried to do it 7 times in a row already. Ended up with the same issue every time.

Comment: Have you tried using different CRAN mirrors? Which one are you currently using? You can change with chooseCRANmirror() function.